# Converting a webpage into a list

Tags: python, html, list, python-3.x

This code is supposed to ask a user to choose a word to search the webpage for. I thought that the simpilest way to do this would be to just put the whole web page onto a list and find out if the word being searched is on the list. I am having 2 problems, the first is: I can't get the page to convert to a list. The second problem is I can't get the prompt to work correctly. Sorry, I am still very new to python, any help at all would be appreciated.

```
#p6 scrabble
#looks for a word in a giant list tells if it is present or not
words=[]
import urllib.request
url='https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/15F/cis122/data/sowpods_short.txt'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as webpage: #opens the webpage
    for line in webpage:
        line= line.strip()
        line= line.decode('utf-8')#unicode
        if line [0] != "#":
            item_list =line.split(',')
words.append(webpage)

prompt=input("press L to search for a word or press q to quit")
while prompt != 'q':
    question= input("type a word to search for ")    
    if question == words:
        print("yes, " , "was in the list")
    elif print("not on the list")
```

Comment: you can't use == to compare one word with list (words) or even with webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import urllib.request

words = []

url='https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/15F/cis122/data/sowpods_short.txt'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as webpage:
    for line in webpage:
        line = line.strip().decode('utf-8')
        if line[0] != "#":
            words += line.split(',')

print(words)

while True:
    question = input("type word or `q` to quit: ")

    if question == 'q':
        break

    if question in words:
        print("yes,", question, " was on the list")
    else:
        print("not on the list")
```

Comment: Thanks again, thats 2 tonight!